# Is it possible to sandbox a cross-domain iframe, then remove the sandbox when it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I tried attaching the onclick event but it seems to not register.

```html
<iframe onclick="alert('it works')" src="https://some-cross-domain-site.com">
```

Using mouse events wouldn't work because those don't exist on mobile. Creating a div over the iframe to catch the first click would break the user experience. Is there a way, possibly without javascript, to remove a cross-domain iframe's sandbox when clicked?

Comment: You want to click an iframe to remove it?

Comment: There is no onclick for iframe. Any click event occurs inside the new window it creates and those events don't bubble to the parent page window (or the iframe element)